# Remove div without content without jQuery (all solutions tried not working)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material

I have a case where I want to display animals in two different ways : when I just see the description page, I want to have the mat-label and description both asides, and when I edit I want to keep the mat-label upon the select or input.

[image]

I have check lots of proposed solution on stackoverflow but no one work and the only way I found is to duplicate code which is a really ugly way to achieve it.
Here's my code:

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" appearance="fill">
   <div class="someMode" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="12px">
     <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput[formControl]="animal.get('name')"/>
   </div>
</mat-form-field>
```

I don't use jquery, and the thing is when I am on the consulting mode, I want the

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="12px">
```

appear, and when I'm on editing mode, I want to remove it (and keep the content).

But everything I've tried give me bad things. Like :

```
changeLayout() {
  this.unwrap(document.querySelector('.someMode');   
}

unwrap(wrapper: any) {
const docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
while (wrapper.firstChild) {
  const child = wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild);
  docFrag.append(child);
}

 wrapper.parentNode.replaceChild(docFrag, wrapper);
}
```

The mat label ends inside the input or mat select.

[image]

I don't really know how to make it I even tried by remove the querySelector on someMode and appendChild inside the mat-form-fields but it doesn't work neither.

Do you have any idea how could I do it please ?

Comment: I hate to tell you, but your description is not clear. The names you use don't seem to match the images, and it all gets confusing very quickly. You are using a templating engine of some sort. Please add that tag to your question, it might help get an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried to remove useless code and be more concise in the code  blocks

Comment: Can't you just add classes on the parent and hide/style the relevant elements (with `display: none`) depending on the class? You don't need to remove elements, just hide them when appropriate.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution the problem is if I hide the <div> in question, all the content will be too, but I want to keep the <mat-label> and the <input> which are inside this problematic div